# How to get build and version number of Flutter app

Tags: flutter, version

I am currently developing an application which is currently in beta mode. Due to this, I would like to show them what version they are on. For example, "v1.0b10 - iOS". So far, I have got this code: `Text("Build: V1.0b10 - " + (Platform.isIOS ? "iOS" : "Android"))`. How would I be able to get the build version and number within flutter?

Comment: see this link: https://blog.maskys.com/how-to-get-the-version-build-number/

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You can use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus).

The versions are extracted from:

Android:

```
build.gradle, versionCode and versionName
```

iOS:

```
Info.plist, CFBundleVersion
```

## Usage

### Add the dependency

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  package_info_plus: ^1.0.6
```

2. Import the file into your dart file:

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
```

3. if your method is marked as `async`:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

If you don't want to use `await/async`:

```
PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
  String appName = packageInfo.appName;
  String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
  String version = packageInfo.version;
  String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
});
```

Comment: In IOS this give version 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.0+6. Can you guide me what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Wajidkhan, 1.0.0 is the version number and 6 is the build number. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app).

Comment: does this means I need to manually modify/maintain different versions for iOS and Android? is there a unified place?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)

only on release apk

Comment: If you want your app working on Web, Android and IOS use "package_info_plus" 
instead. https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus.

Comment: use the new version from https://pub.dev/packages/package_info/install

Comment: how about not use package/library ? there is any alternative ?

Comment: If you get `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)` error, try to reinstall the app completely

Answer (score 113):

***Note**: This answer has been updated to reflect the fact that the [package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info) plugin is deprecated and redirects to [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus).*

### Version name and build number

At development time, you can easily find the version name and build number of a Flutter or Dart project by inspecting **pubspec.yaml**. Here is an example:

```yaml
version: 1.1.0+2
```

This is case the version name is `1.1.0` and the build number is `2`.

However, if you want to get these values at runtime, you should use a plugin.

### Add the dependency

In **pubspec.yaml** add the [`package_info_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) package.

```
dependencies:
  package_info_plus: ^1.0.2
```

Update the version number to the [current](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) one.

### Import the package

In the file that you need it, add the following import.

```dart
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
```

### Get the version name and code

In your code you can get the app version name and code like this:

```dart
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
String version = packageInfo.version;
String code = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

### See also

- [How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app)
- [How to get build and version number of Flutter Web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647071/how-to-get-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-web-app/60647072#60647072)

Comment: I don't see how this is different than accepted answer?

Comment: @Volleyball, at the time I answered the question, the accepted answer was much shorter (check the edit history). Later that user added a lot of content so they are basically the same now.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that, you are right, your answer should be the accepted one, +1 from me.

Comment: `package_info_plus` - nice. Thanks so much for sharing. Like it more than  `package_info` as it supports more platforms.

Comment: More about the deprecated packages plugins here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/README.md#deprecated

Answer (score 16):

install [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus), then you can use it directly with future builder in your widget tree:

```dart
 FutureBuilder<PackageInfo>(
              future: PackageInfo.fromPlatform(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Text(
                        'Version: ${snapshot.data!.version}',),
                      );
                  default:
                    return const SizedBox();
                }
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 7):

RE the multiple references to `package_info`, please note that this package has been deprecated and the recommended replacement is the [Flutter Community Plus Plugins](https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/) version, [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus).

Comment: version number for me is always unknown

Answer (score 5):

For using it from command line or CLI, you need a pure Dart code.

I used the following script:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

String pathToYaml = join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), '../pubspec.yaml');

Future<YamlMap> loadPubspec() async => loadYaml(await File(pathToYaml).readAsString());

void main() async {
  var pubspec = await loadPubspec();
  print(pubspec['version'].toString().split('+')[0]);
}
```

You can run it from the project root folder:

```
dart run scripts/get_version_name.dart
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `new_version` plugin. Using this plugin you can get installed App Version, Playstore App Version and app url which can redirect to playstore.

[New Version Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version)

```
void versionCheck() async {
    final NewVersion newVersion = NewVersion(context: context);
    VersionStatus versionStatus = await newVersion.getVersionStatus();
    if (versionStatus != null && versionStatus.canUpdate) {
      await ConfirmDialog(
          context: context,
          title: 'Update Available',
          body: Text('A new version, ${versionStatus.storeVersion}, is available.'),
          acceptButton: 'Update Now',
          cancelButton: 'Update Later'
      ).then((ConfirmAction res) async {
        if (res == ConfirmAction.CONFIRM && await canLaunch(versionStatus.appStoreLink)) {
          await launch(versionStatus.appStoreLink, forceWebView: false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Custom Alert Dialog Box

```
enum ConfirmAction{ CONFIRM, CANCEL }
Future<ConfirmAction> ConfirmDialog({
  BuildContext context,
  String title,
  Widget body,
  String acceptButton,
  String cancelButton
})
=> showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
      title: Wrap(
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        spacing: 4,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title)
        ],
      ),
      content: Wrap(
        runSpacing: 10,
        children: <Widget>[
          body,
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: Text(acceptButton ?? 'Confirm'),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(ConfirmAction.CONFIRM);
            }
        ),
        FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: Text(cancelButton ?? 'Cancel'),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(ConfirmAction.CANCEL);
            }
        ),
      ],
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter mobile applications the version number is in `pubspec.yaml` file. like below:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

To get the version name and code, add the `package_info` dependency into `pubspec.yaml` file, like below:

```
dependencies:
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16
```

And

```
import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart'; // import the package_info

Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final _packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
          String AppName = _packageInfo.appName;
          String PackageName = _packageInfo.packageName;
          String AppVersion = _packageInfo.version;
          String BuildNumber = _packageInfo.buildNumber;
          String BuildSignature = _packageInfo.buildSignature;
    });
  }
```