# Is there a way to get the previous version of an app or know if it has been updated or downloaded?

Tags: flutter, version

I was trying to build a feature announcement where I can tell the users that there is a new feature available on my flutter app.

The problem is that I don’t want to show this if someone just downloaded the app, since they are new users anyway, I just want to show that to users that were using the app before.

Is there a way to know previous versions of the app that were installed or if the app was updated vs just downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

*First of All there is `package` to find your app current `version` `number` and `build number`, I have used this personally with the **backend** to show some `new` **features** to our new **users**.*

1. Add this to your *package's* pubspec.yaml file:

   `package_info: ^0.4.0+16`
2. Now `import` the statement into your *dart* file

   `import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';`
3. And use this if your `method` is marked as `async`:

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

```
String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

Now, What you have to do is that send the current version number in your API,
And have a Current Version Value stored in **backend**, To check for the Versions you are sending in the **API's** and Compare them to show new Features,

*Like Say If I am old User, So My APP Version number is 1 and API's is sending 1 in the backend too.*

*But If I am new User then, My APP version is number greater than 1 and API's is sending version number greater than 1, And I can see the update in the app if My Version number is greater than 1 as a new User.*

Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672255/9577961) For More Reference to use the Package
Sorry For bad English