# How to get build version number of native dart software

Tags: dart

I want to get my native dart software build and version number which exists in pubspac.yaml

[image]

My software gets converted in the end to executable using the `dart2native` so I guess that the final executable file does not include the actual `pubspec.yaml` file.

I can't use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) as suggested in [many places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672171/how-to-get-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app) because I run **native Dart** code and **not Flutter** app.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a pubspec file with [pubspec_parse](https://pub.dev/packages/pubspec_parse). Then you can retrieve the version number.

```dart
final file = File('pubspec.yaml');

final content = Pubspec.parse(await file.readAsString());

print(content.version); // 1.1.2+41
```

Comment: Do you think that I can read it even when got transformed into executable and the pubspec.yaml got removed?

Comment: If you were to read the file's contents `file.readAsString()` before the file was deleted, you would be able to use it. But you can't read a file that doesn't exist any more