# How to get app build number in flutter from pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter

I need to access version from pubspec.yaml and display it in a screen. How can I get this possibly without using any packages. Any answer would be highly appreciated. Thank You

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je2I8.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) package. According to the example, usage is in below.

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

...

// Be sure to add this line if `PackageInfo.fromPlatform()` is called before runApp()
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

...

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672171/how-to-get-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app) answer